# How can I write a program that helps me to perform a set of process repeatedly on a website?

Tags: web

Step 1. Enter an ID, FSXXXXXX
[image]

Step 2. Click "Return Order" then click "OK" in the pop-up window 
[image]

Step 3. After it finished loading, click "Receive."
[image]

Now I have to repeat this set of steps for more than 1000 different IDs. Therefore, I am seeking for help. Is there any way that I can automate the whole process ?

Comment: Autohotkey could do that for you, if you are on Windows. It can read a text file with the IDs and perform clicks and wait or input data.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to control the Chrome browser. You can programmatically control the browser in exactly the same way as if you were using a mouse. You identify the element you need using XPath, which you get from Chrome Developer Tools - Inspect Element.

You would read your IDs from a text file or database, loop through them all and click the buttons.

You can watch Selenium interact with the browser and can also easily troubleshoot with Developer Tools if there is an uncaught error.

I use Python to do this.  Selenium supports other languages.